# Extracting JPG frames from webcam MJPG stream using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, webcam, video-capture

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2. My application is the front-end of a video pipeline and entails extracting video frames from a webcam, possibly cropping and/or rotating them (90, 180, 270 deg), and then distributing them to one or more other pieces of code for further processing. The overall system tries to maximize efficiency at every step to e.g., improve options for adding functionality later on (compute power and bandwidth wise).

Functionally, I have the front-end working, but I want to improve its efficiency by processing JPEG frames extracted from the camera's MJPEG stream. This would allow efficient, lossless cropping and rotation in the JPEG domain, e.g. using [jpegtran-cffi](https://github.com/jbaiter/jpegtran-cffi), and distribution of compressed frames that are smaller than the corresponding decoded ones. JPEG decoding will take place if/when/where necessary, with an overall expected gain. As an extra benefit, this approach allows efficient saving of the webcam video without loss of image quality due to decoding + re-coding.

The problem I run into is that OpenCV's VideoCapture class does not seem to allow access to the MJPEG stream:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture()
cam.open(0)
if not cam.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
else:
    enabled = True
    while enabled:
        enabled, frame = cam.read()
        # do stuff
```

Here, `frame` is always in component (i.e., decoded) format. I looked at using `cam.grab() + cam.retrieve()` instead of `cam.read()` with the same result (in line with the OpenCV documentation). I also tried `cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)` but that only converts the decoded video to RGB (if it is in another component format) and does not prevent decoding. BTW I verified that the camera uses the MJPEG codec (via `cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)`).

So my questions are: am I missing something or will this approach not work? If the latter, is there an alternative?

A final point: the application has to be able to control the webcam within its capabilities; e.g., frame size, frame rate, exposure, gain, ... This is nicely supported by cv2.VideoCapture.

Thanks!

===

Follow-up: in absence of the solution I was looking for, I added explicit JPEG encoding:

```
jpeg_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), _JPEG_QUALITY])[1]
```

with `_JPEG_QUALITY` set to 90 (out of 100). While this adds computation and reduces image quality, both in principle redundant, it allows me to experiment with trade-offs.  --KvZ

Comment: did you get the solution to the problem? I too want to add some functionality on the JPEG format like JPEG DCT analysis.

Comment: I stayed with the explicit JPEG encoding; the advantages (JPEG-domain processing, JPEG distribution) outweighed the disadvantages in my case (extra computation, slightly reduced image quality).